# PHP Include or copy paste mysql login info on every page?

Tags: php, mysql, database, security, admin

Is it safe to use php_include file for mysql login information or is is better to copy/paste the login info for mysql on every page? If you go with php_include, how will you block that file from being seen?

Comment: Being seen on the client side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a connection.php

```
$host   =   "localhost";  //server
$user   =   "user";  //username
$pass   =   "pass"; //password
$db =   "db1"; //database
$con    =   @mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);  //connection
if(!$con){
  die("Could Not Connect to $host: ".mysql_error());
  } //if NOT connected force error
$db_select  =   @mysql_select_db($db);  // database connection
if(!$db_select){
  die("Could Not Select $db: ".mysql_error());
  }  //if NOT connected force error
```

Put this file connection.php outside your /www or /public_html folder

---

Add

```
require_once("../whereeverthismaybe/connection.php");
```

as the first line on every page you need it for.

-jt

Comment: Thanks Taylor.  When you say put this outside any of your public_hmtl folder, you mean a separate folder that doesn't have any website files right?

Comment: yes and a folder that has no "access" from the web.  A typical structure would be home/{files/folders}/public_html for your website.  Anything "above" the public_html will be not accessible from the web, but when the .php is processed internally your web files will have access.. this prevents unauthorized access to your login information.

Answer (score 4):

Use an include with the .php include set outside the html root (usually /var/www or public_html)

Comment: @Gazier.  Thanks for the response but new to the game.  Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Where is your document root?  As in, the folder you upload to which http://yoursite.com points to?  Put it somewhere above that folder.

Comment: You mean to put it in any folder or section other than where they website content is uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

Even if that file is in the public_html it shouldn't echo/display the information nor be downloadable by browser so you are okay in that regard. You can block directory access to where it is with the httpd/apache2.conf file or .htaccess assuming this is an apache server.

Also I've been told by some dev's before to use require_once instead but that's up to you.

Comment: thanks for the response.  How do you configure the apache2.conf file to block files from being downloaded via the browser or any other way?

Comment: that's a bit more complicated but try an .htaccess file first because it's much simpler. place a file called ".htaccess" inside of the same directory as the included php file.

Comment: "deny from all" should be the the file's contents, this is a great resource -> http://www.htpasswdgenerator.com/apache/htaccess.html